# Website layout broken in webkit, but corrects after reload

Tags: html, css, layout, webkit

EDIT - UPDATE:  It turned out the issue was a simple float problem, resolved with .header h1{ float:left;}. But I'm still curious about why the problem occurred with Safari and Chrome in the first place, and why a reload corrected it. So I've left the original uncorrected code in case anyone is interested in diagnosing.

Original Message:
I'm baffled. When loading my website for the first time in either Chrome or Safari (firefox is fine) the navigation displays incorrectly. However, when I reload/refresh the page the layout problem (usually, depending on the browser and OS) disappears and displays as intended. It also (again, usually) corrects if I change the browser window size (shrink then expand) - so, after a media query that changes the navigation takes effect.
Also, if I close the browser completely and then open the webpage the problem is there again.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the layout breaking? - SOLVED.
2. Why does a browser reload or media query firing correct the problem?

Here is the code I think is relevant. I'm new to this, so my css may have some strange and redundant code.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><h2>Logo</h2></div>
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <div class="nav">
    <ul><li><a href="#">Link1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link3</a></li></ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Subject</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header h1, .nav{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    float: right;
}

.nav ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

.nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Here is the media query, in case it's relevant

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
    .header h1{
    display: none;
    }
    .logo h2{
        display: inline;   
    }
    .header{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav{
        float: none;
        margin-left: -12px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    .wrap{
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
     .header h3{
        margin-top: -70px;
         margin-left: -12px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added `position: relative` in the below `.nav ul div`. But what will be about the other divs, they have default static positioning . I think that is the problem .Be assure that each div has relative positioning and re-position others div in their corresponding exact position.

```
.nav ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    /*relative positioning others are static default change them in relative */
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```